# Dynamic backgroudImage :after element

Tags: reactjs, mdbootstrap

I am new to react, I have been trying to implement parallax effect I have currently defined -

```
<section className="section parallax backgroundImageProp"></section>
```

and I am using the css to provide the background Image -

```
.backgroundImageProp::after{
background-image: url('https://republic-prod.azureedge.net/republic-prod/stories/promolarge/xxhdpi/15207762165aa53418177b5.jpeg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

}

Currently the image is hardcoded I want it to be rendered dynamically, but I am unable to do so after multiple attempts, I am using the below style to add the css -

```
var backgroundImageAfter = {
  after:{backgroundImage:'url(' + image_url + ')'},
};

<section className="section parallax" style={backgroundImageAfter}>
</section>
```

but this also did not help. I am missing something here. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a `div` with `style={backgroundImageAfter}` after `section` element and remove the after from the style object.

```
var backgroundImageAfter = {
  backgroundImage:'url(' + image_url + '),
};

<section className="section parallax">
</section>
<div style={backgroundImageAfter}></div>
```

Comment: Tried the same but did not help :(

Comment: @PraveenPandey why did not help? It's the most simple way to solve the problem.